# Is it possible to open link in Mercury, Dolphin, Atomic on iOS like Chrome does

Tags: ios, browser

OpenInChromeController(https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/ios-links) allows us to open link in Chrome on iOS.

Is there any similar libs for Mercury, Dolphin and Atomic?

Answer (score 0):

If the other browser support custom URL-schemes, you can call them by their specific URL-scheme. Chrome is called by googlechrome://

The library-documentation explains what can be done in addition for example to forward the user to the AppStore if the app is not installed.

I did not find any URL-Scheme description for Mercury for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Choosy](https://github.com/substantial/choosy), an open-source project I wrote to solve this problem (and not just for browsers).